# How to activate a Fragment Identifier programmatically

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl Google Local's business reviews to pull review information programmatically. I am using Python because once the script is done, it has to be constructed as such to allow it's functions to be imported into a larger Python application.

The input the application can expect will be Google urls like this:

```
https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=amy%27s+ice+cream&rflfq=1&rlha=0&tbm=lcl&lrd=0x8644b130384298d3:0xad33336b7377c5a6,1&rlfi=hd:;si:12480375528965522854
```

As you can see in the above URL, there is a fragment identifier.
This is what causes the reviews to be rendered (via Javascript), removing it loads a general search results page. I need to be able to activate this fragment identified programmatically so I can crawl the review content. I am unsure how to do this. I have tried just passing the whole URL, rendering the entire page via web-kit, and then parsing what is rendered, but it seems to be skipping or excluding the fragment identifier. I am not sure how best to proceed.

Comment: When rendering via webKit, is it running the full page's Javascript?  Can you tell if there are any script errors?  Can you see any evidence that the Javascript in the page is running?

Comment: I am not getting any indication any javascript is actually executing

Comment: I'd suggest you try a very simple page in your web-kit engine that perhaps just does `document.write("hello");` into the page and you can see that content.  If not, then you have to figure out why your engine is not running the JS.